# PHP Array issue (beginner)

Tags: php, arrays, random, count, array-push

I'm receiving an integer value from my array, instead of a name. How can i correct my code to randomly select a name from the array?

```
$family = array();
        array_push($family, "joe");
        array_push($family, "bill");
        array_push($family, "carl");
    $sorted = sort($family);
    $select = rand(0, count($sorted) - 1);

    echo $select;
```

Comment: `echo $family[$select];` ?

Comment: Just wondering but have you got any idea of what you are doing here? Look at array_rand, that should be what you need.

Comment: thanks frz. and i'm working on it bart. only my second day. and i'm following codecademy, so array_rand hasn't been discussed yet.

Comment: "php randomly pick from array." first google answer is ...

Comment: And `sort()` doesn't return an array.

Answer (score 1):

1. `sort()` doesn't return the sorted array, it sorts the passed array by reference.
2. Using `rand()` as you do will return a random index to use in the array like: `echo $family[$select];`.

If you don't need the array sorted for later an easier approach would be:

```
shuffle($family);
echo $family[0];
```

Or if you do need it sorted:

```
sort($family);
echo $family[array_rand($family)];
```

Comment: i think your mixing the sorting and the random picking up. with or without sorting i would not use shuffle (then pick 0), over array_rand. i would think the latter was more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
$sorted = sort($family);
 $select = rand(0, count($sorted) - 1);
 echo $select;
```

Replaced by,

```
asort($family);
$select = array_rand($family);
echo "Randomly Selected array value==" . $family[$select];
```